# "to-know-each-other" or "knowing-each-other"

Tags: word-usage, adjectives

> We gave the new members a **to-know-each-other** break.
>
> We gave the new members a **knowing-each-other** break.

What it means is: *the boy came back to the break that was scheduled so that guests had the chance to know each other*.

Which one is the right version? (I'm also open to others).

Comment: A) It should be `resuming`, B)Neither implies what you mean

Comment: First of all, you don't "**go back to** a break", you "**come back from** a break". So if he "resumed" conversing with the other guests, the "break" was the time he was **not** with them. Please try to reword your question along these lines, then we'll talk about your bold hyphenated phrasings.

Comment: A social break? This is often called "Social Activity (Break)" on conference schedules.

Comment: @Brian Hitchcock How about now?

Comment: still not right.  Just say "The break was scheduled...".  Mentioning that the boy went to (or came from) the break confuses things; it is not needed in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm constrained to a hyphenated expression I'd probably go with a *getting-to-know-you* break, after the song from *The King and I*.

But I think the more ordinary way of expressing this would be something like

> We broke for a ***mixer***, to get to know the new members.

It's an American use: [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/mixer), def. 2.

*Broke* might be *adjourned*, if the session was the last of the day.

Comment: Good one. "Mixer" sounds right. +1. But could you please add a citation or link for that definition of mixer?

Comment: @BrianHitchcock There you go.